# ng-modal inside ng-repeat not updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am a new bee to AngularJs2 application.

Basically am trying to run below function, to dynamically create rows from the Object List, and populate a td value based on the multiplication of first two td elements.

The value of ItemCost is set dynamically in the Controller as

```
$('#sparesCost_'+elementId).val(ui.item.orgObj.sparesCost);
```

Now the Spares_Total Cost is calculated as ItemTotalCost = (ItemQty * ItemCost) like below line

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sparesTotal_{{$index}}" id="sparesTotal_{{$index}}" ng-value="item.cost * item.qty"></td>
```

However the value TotalCost is not updated dynamically from the Controller .val() event

If the user manually updates the Cost for the row, then the TotalCost is updated

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in spares.items">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" name="sparesCode_{{$index}}" id="sparesCode_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.sparesCode" typeahead="spare for spare in $ctrl.spares | filter:$viewValue"></td>           
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" name="sparesCost_{{$index}}" id="sparesCost_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.cost" ng-required></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control " name="sparesQty_{{$index}}" id="sparesQty_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.qty" ng-required ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sparesTotal_{{$index}}" id="sparesTotal_{{$index}}" ng-value="item.cost * item.qty"></td>                         
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you fail? Check http://angular.io before asking Angular2 questions.

Comment: are you talking about angular 1 or angular 2 ?

Comment: im working on angular2